# Given a string in C, how can I know if it is encoded in ASCII or Unicode?

Tags: c, string, unicode, encoding, ascii

Given a string in C, how can I know if it is encoded in ASCII or Unicode?

We know nothing else.

Comment: Real ASCII, with no characters above 127, or "[extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)"? UTF-8, UTF-16, or something else?

Comment: Leaving aside the fact that there is no such thing as "the unicode" - rather, it is a family of related unicode encodings, it is usually a job of whomever gives you the string to tell you what's the encoding.

Comment: may be this helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523217/detect-encoding-of-a-string-in-c-c

Comment: Short answer: you don't. Longer answer: you can make a fairly reasonable guess, but can almost never be entirely certain.

Comment: Some notes on how Windows Notepad does it and various consequences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx  (be sure to follow the various links, too).

Comment: You should read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: If I were a jackass, I would tell you that "if it's ASCII, then it has got to be Unicode too." Is your question really how can you tell if a C string is UTF-8 encoded or references a codepage like Windows-1250? That's doable.

Comment: @cleong: It's doable only if the string contains characters with values above 127, and even then it's not always possible. It's possible for a string to be invalid UTF-8 (for example, if byte of the form `110xxxxx` is not followed by a byte of the form `10xxxxxx`). But Windows-1250 assigns meanings to all 256 bytes values, so *any* byte sequence could be valid Windows-1250.

Comment: Well, the 7th bit is set on all "regular" Latin characters. There's a pretty good chance, therefore, that a detectable illegal UTF-8 sequence would appear in codepage text.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a deep and subtle problem. There are some easy cases that can be culled off. The rest is not so easy.

For example, if the string begins with a Unicode byte order mark, then it might be safe to assume the string is Unicode. Not all Unicode strings will begin with a BOM however.

If every byte of the string has its eighth bit clear, then it might be safe to assume that it is 7-bit ASCII. If true, then it is of course also valid UTF-8. But it could be encoded in the rarely seen but well defined UTF-7, where all byte are guaranteed to use only seven bits leaving room for parity or other sources of damage in a communications channel.

You could scan the string (or at least a prefix of the string) and test for compliance with well-formed UTF-8. If it passes, it might be UTF-8. Of course, it might be in some other encoding and just happen to comply by luck.

Scanning for compliance with UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE is similarly possible, but with the same caveats.

Raymond Chen [wrote about this in his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx), from the point of view of how should Notepad treat a file.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "Unicode", which is a set of characters and a standard for their properties, not an encoding. Unicode specifies several encodings such as UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32.

If you want to know whether the text is ASCII or UTF-8, and those are the only possibilities, the answer is that it's always UTF-8, and might also be ASCII (if and only if it contains no bytes greater than 127).

If it might be ASCII or UTF-16, you can likewise determine for certain that it's UTF-16 if it contains any bytes greater than 127, but if it contains only bytes in the range 0-127, it could technically be either ASCII or UTF-16. You can of course use heuristics to judge what characters/patterns are likely and get a very reasonable guess as to the intended meaning unless the text is extremely short.