# C file to check if file is empty or contains ASCII text

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, ascii, fopen

I'm trying to write a program which should be able to take a file as input in terminal and then determine if the file is empty or written in ASCII text. But I keep getting segmentation fault 11.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char c;
    int size;

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    fseek(&c, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);

    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("file is empty\n");
    }

    fclose(file);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    c = fgetc(file);

    if (c != EOF && c <= 127)
    {
        printf("ASCII\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: `fseek` didnt you mean `file` instead of `&c` ?

Comment: Where does your code crash? Run it in a debugger and find out. Also, you don't check the return value from `fopen`

Comment: This is a good opportunity to look into debugging. Just run your program in GDB and tell us where it crashes. One option: You don't care about return values much, do you?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: I'm sure reading the warnings would help.

Comment: ... and `fget` returns an `int`, so `unsigned char c;` -> `int c;`

Comment: [`ftell()` returns `long`, not `int`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html)

Comment: You also should check all the characters in a loop until the end of file. The first one could be ascii and another can be UTF-8!

Comment: @Zorgatone Or completely random binary.

Comment: Yeah, of course @TripeHound

Comment: A file is only ASCII text if it was written as such. Only the writer can tell you. The current contents being compatible with ASCII doesn't imply that the future contents will be compatible with ASCII. And, being compatible with ASCII doesn't even imply the content is text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1] fseek doesnt have first argument `unsgined char*`, but `FILE*`.

`fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);`

2] You shouldn't use `unsigned char` / `char` for checking for `EOF`, use `int` for sure.

3] Working and simplier code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        // err we havent filename
        return 1;
    }

    int c;

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        // err failed to open file
        return 1;
    }

    c = fgetc(file);

    if (c == EOF)
    {
        printf("empty\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ungetc(c, file);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c < 0 || c > 127)
        {
            // not ascii
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("ascii\n");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip! It works, however I would also like to check for ISO-8859, I tried extending the code as follows :
 if(c != EOF && (c <= 127 && (c >= 160 && c <= 255)))
    {
        printf("ISO-8859 text\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
        
    }

But the file can only return as empty or ASCII. It always returns as being ASCII even if the file contains ISO-8859 symbols, do you have any ideas as to why ? :-)

Comment: @MyTivoli You are welcome, glad it help. Yes you can improve it as you need to. You can now mark it as answered :-)

Comment: `if (c <= 256)` hardy qualifies as a test for ASCII contents. You should read the whole file and verify that all bytes are in the range 32 to 126 inclusive plus some selected control bytes such as `'\r'`, `'\n'`, `'\t'`, `'\f'`...

Comment: @MyTivoli Just found out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523217/detect-encoding-of-a-string-in-c-c) may help you with detecting which character set it is :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
fseek(&c, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Here you are supposed to pass file descriptor, like

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Answer (score 1):

fseek takes a FILE* as a parameter and you are giving it a  unsigned char* - change &c to file.