# Data types specification ASCII, ISO-8859, UTF-8 Unicode in C program

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Im trying to create a c program which takes a file as input from command line and determines what the files type is. 
My options are

1. empty
2. ASCII text
3. ISO-8859 text
4. UTF-8 Unicode

When I have to create the if statements I have written for ASCII:

`if(c != EOF && c <= 127)`

For ISO-8859 i have written:

`if((c != EOF && c <= 127) || (c >= 160 && c<= 255))`

These two works when I feed them files with the input they should be able to specify. However when I got to UTF-8 Unicode, my if statement looked like this:

`if(c != EOF && c <= 255)`

And that doesn't work. I keep getting the wrong result.

Can anyone help me on how to specify UTF-8 Unicode text further?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523217/detect-encoding-of-a-string-in-c-c) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 doesn't allow the 192-193 and 245-255 ranges; however it's not like they turn out *that* frequently in ISO-8859-1 text, and personally I wouldn't really rely upon the "120-160 gap", as Windows-1252, often used interchangeably as ISO-8859-1<sup>1</sup>, doesn't have it.

A way more reliable way to detect if a file is UTF-8 is, instead of just checking for byte ranges, to check if its multibyte sequences are conforming [to the UTF-8 "syntax"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

```
FILE *fp = ...;
int ch;
bool good_utf8 = true;
bool good_ascii = true;
bool empty = true;
bool good_iso8859_1 = true;
while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) {
    empty = false;
    int extra = 0;
    if(ch>>7 == 0) {
        // ok, if the high bit is not set it's a "regular" character
    } else {
        // ASCII never has the high bit set
        good_ascii = false;
        // ISO8859-1 gap
        if(ch>=120 && ch<= 160) good_iso8859_1 = false;
        // check if it's a valid UTF-8 multibyte sequence
        if((ch>>5) == 6) {
            // 110xxxxx => one continuation byte
            extra = 1;
        } else if((ch>>4) == 14) {
            // 1110xxxx => two continuation bytes
            extra = 2;
        } else if((ch>>3) == 30) {
            // 11110xxx => three continuation bytes
            extra = 3;
        } else {
            // there's no other valid UTF-8 sequence prefix
            good_utf8 = false;
        }
    }
    for(; good_utf8 && extra > 0; --extra) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch>=120 && ch<= 160) good_iso8859_1 = false;
        // all the stated continuation bytes must be present,
        // and they have to follow the 10xxxxxx pattern
        if(ch==EOF || ((ch>>6) != 2)) {
            good_utf8 = false;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

---

1. ISO-8859 is not a single charset, it's multiple related ones; I'm assuming you are talking about ISO-8859-1 (AKA "Latin1") because you are talking about the 120-160 gap; if instead you have to detect *which* variant of ISO-8859, you have to check against different gaps.

Comment: "*A way more reliable way to detect if a file is UTF-8 is ... to check if its multibyte sequences are conforming to the UTF-8 syntax*" - same goes for the other formats. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so an ASCII file will pass a UTF-8 test, but you have to check if the bytes are in the ASCII table of defined characters. That is easy to do with a simple `<= 127` test...

Comment: ... But you can't just do a simple range check like `<= 255` (which BTW will always be true, since a byte can never exceed 255) with the various ISO-8859-X formats, because each ISO-8859 defines different ranges of bytes as valid (and some do have gaps in them), and they define common bytes outside of the ASCII range as mapping to different Unicode codepoints. To detect a specific ISO-8859-X format, you have to test the individual file bytes against that format's table of defined values. There is no single test to say "the file is any ISO-8859", you have to test each one until you find a match

Comment: Yeah, the code in the answer essentially checks if i's iso8859-1, as OP somehow implied; still, the general idea is to go by exclusion - ASCII is easy, UTF-8 is easy, if it's not any of the two probably it's some ISO-8859.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: also: "same goes for the other formats" - not really, UTF-8 is different as ISO-8859 encodings don't have multibyte sequences with a fixed, well-recognizable syntax - they may have gaps in their character table, but once the critical characters are avoided any sequence goes, so they are way more difficult to detect reliably (which is the reason why most good "charset guessers", after excluding "impossible" encodings with forbidden ranges, compare the character frequencies against "average" character frequency tables for languages used in a given encoding).