# How to use Unicode symbols/emojis in raw string literals in MSVC

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, character-encoding

Is there any way of determening what specific encoding my std::string would use? What about how this will be handled from std::string position if string will look like this `std::string("This is a test");` and another one is going to use non-ASCII symbols like `std::string("This is a russian alphabet: Ребята сдохли");`? I need to know this so I could convert this type of a string with "const char*" as a constructor argument to UTF-8 encoded std::string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to my problem was `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`. This line gave me ability to use strings like this `string data("");` and it is getting properly encoded by MSVS into [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOJEj.jpg)

Comment: Yes, the compiler emits literal strings using the directed "execution charset".

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `std::string` encoding. A `std::string` contains bytes. Period. It's a `std::vector<char>` with some ASCII-friendly helper functions.

Those bytes may be interpreted in near-infinite ways — as ASCII, as UTF-8, as Shift-JIS… in some situations you can sort of guess at the encoding if you know enough about the problem domain, and [you could do things like looking for a UTF-8 BOM at the start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7523400/560648), but the absence of one doesn't mean the string isn't UTF-8 and the presence of one doesn't even necessarily mean that it is — it could be some bytes that happen to look like a BOM (that linked answer seems optimistic to me). In general this is like trying to get oil out of water.

If you need to know the encoding of a sequence of bytes you receive, you'll need the entity that sends them to tell you what that encoding is (some Exif fields use an 8-char tag prefix in ASCII that announces the encoding of the remainder of the text block), or otherwise document an agreement that both ends will use e.g. UTF-8, then require that this agreement is adhered to, and kick out error messages/exceptions if an incompatible byte sequence is encountered.

Personally I tend to assume ASCII or UTF-8 (as required) throughout my applications, and at the point of input do a conversion if I'm getting text from a source that's known to encode as something else.

Don't forget also that if your string isn't ASCII (or another single-byte encoding) then elementwise operations on it are not going to work properly. You'd need a library that interprets the component, encoding-domain *characters* of the string and works at that resolution, rather than at the byte level. Plenty of existing decent libraries exist to manage the various Unicodey encodings.